# how to reset slideshowSpeed when we click on next or previous button of flexslider

Tags: c#, asp.net

My flex silder code

```
 $(function () {
        mySlider =  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "fade",
            controlsContainer: ".flex-container",
            directionNav: false,
            controlNav: true,
            slideshow: true,
            slideshowSpeed: 5000,
            pauseOnHover: true,
            pauseOnAction: true,
        });
    })
```

On click on next and previous button, i have this function

```
 $(document).on('click', '.slides>li .next', function () {
        debugger;
        $('.slider').flexslider('next');
        return false;
    });
```

When we click on next and previous button, I want to reset  `slideshowSpeed` to start from 0 to 5 sec again because the functionality of button click and the slideshow is firing at the same time when `slideshowSpeed`  reaches to 5 sec.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
mySlider.flexAnimate(0);
```

Or reinitialize it:

```
mySlider.flexslider();
```